# problem calling a php method from within itself

Tags: php, recursion

```
class styleFinder{

function styleFinder(){

}

function getFilesNFolders($folder){

    $this->folder = $folder ;
    if($this->folder==""){
        $this->folder = '.';
    }
    if ($handle = opendir($this->folder)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                echo "$file<br /> ";
                if(is_dir($file)){

                    echo "<b>" . $file . " is a folder</b><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with contents ";
                    $this::getFilesNFolders($file);
                   # echo "Found folder";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```

}
I wan to print out a complete tree of folders and files, the script is going into the first folders and finding the files, then finding any sub folders, but not subfolders of those (and yes there is some). Any ideas please?

Comment: Why the `::`? Use `$this->getFilesNFolders($file);` for one thing.

Comment: Static calls are made using `self::method()` or `parent::method()`, but you can't reference object state in a static call (`->` is not allowed).  Think of static calls as being functional: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Comment: Except that `parent::method()` is not actually a static call.  It's a call that depends on the access type of the original method (if the original was accessed as an instance, then the parent call will have access to `$this`).  So that's a special case (and a non-intuitive one to say the least)...

Answer (score 7):

```
$this::getFilesNFolders($file);
```

Should Be

```
$this->getFilesNFolders($file);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP 5.1.2 you have this usefull class available: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a class function is done like this:

```
$this->functionName():
```

Answer (score 1):

Since no one provided that yet, here is the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` version of your code:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/directory'),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $fileObject) {
    if($fileObject->isDir()) {
        echo "<strong>$fileObject is a folder:</strong><br>\n";
    } else {
        echo $fileObject, "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, much more than I'd expected, I had no idea these existed! Thanks everyone else for chipping in too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, within the method itself, you need to call getFilesNFolders with `$this -> getFilesNFolders($file)`.  Also, the way the code is posted you're missing a } at the end, but since there is one starting the text after the code, that is probably a typo.  The code below worked for me (I ran via the command line, so added code to indent different directory levels and also to output \n's):

```
<?php

class StyleFinder{
function StyleFinder(){
}

function getFilesNFolders($folder, $spaces){

    $this->folder = $folder ;
    if($this->folder==""){
        $this->folder = '.';
    }
    if ($handle = opendir($this->folder)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($file)){
                    echo $spaces . "<b>" . $file . " is a folder</b><br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;with contents:\n";
                    $this -> getFilesNFolders($file, $spaces . "  ");
                } else {
                    echo $spaces . "$file<br />\n";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
}

$sf = new StyleFinder();
$sf -> getFilesNFolders(".", "");

?>
```